# LinkedIn SDK is giving authentication error

Tags: android, linkedin-api

I am integrating LinkedIn Login in my app but it is giving me an error

here is the code of Authentication

```
private static Scope buildScope() {
        return Scope.build(Scope.R_BASICPROFILE, Scope.R_EMAILADDRESS, Scope.W_SHARE);
    }

    public void signInWithLinkedIn() {
        //First check if user is already authenticated or not and session is valid or not
        if (!LISessionManager.getInstance(this).getSession().isValid()) {
            //if not valid then start authentication
            LISessionManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).init(this, buildScope()//pass the build scope here
                    , new AuthListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAuthSuccess() {
                            //on successful authentication fetch basic profile data of user
                            fetchBasicProfileData();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAuthError(LIAuthError error) {
                            // Handle authentication errors
                            Log.e(TAG, "Auth Error :" + error.toString());
                            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Failed to authenticate with LinkedIn. Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }, true);//if TRUE then it will show dialog if
            // any device has no LinkedIn app installed to download app else won't show anything
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You are already authenticated.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            fetchBasicProfileData();
        }

    }
```

This is the error:-

> Auth Error :{
>         "errorCode": "UNKNOWN_ERROR",
>         "errorMessage": "The passed in mobile identifier is invalid \"com.tablefortwo\""
>       }

Comment: Are u able to found solution of this issue even i'm facing same issue let me know if you fix this issue....